# Why is Robert Egger's The Lighthouse not nominated at the Oscars 2020?

Tags: academy-awards

I've watched The Lighthouse recently. It's a great movie, striking performances both from Willem Dafoe and Robert Pattinson and a sharp script from brothers Robert and Max Eggers.

And I thought to myself: "Well, that's Oscars material". But when I went to see the Oscars 2020 list of nominees, I didn't find any nomination.

So it is just another snub or was there some sort of rule preventing the film to be nominated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect. *The Lighthouse* does, in fact, have [one Oscar nomination](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls049728933/), for Best Cinematography. So it wasn't ineligible, nor was it snubbed entirely. Why it wasn't nominated for any further awards is, unfortunately, a question for the Academy; I will have to check whether they have made any statements on the matter, but I suspect they won't have done.